How $f$ does differentiable at the end points of the closed interval?
I know a function cannot be differentiable at the end points of the interval. But I wonder why does the author has mentioned $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ exists?

Also I found the same result on wikipedia!!

I am very confused why this so? Even the author has not introduced one sided derivatives! I will really appreciate any help, thank you.

I can't really speak for a book which I don't know and which I don't desire to read, but the results are equivalent thanks to this observation. Let $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ be a function; the following are equivalent: 1) $f$ s differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}$ both exist in $\Bbb R$. 2) There are an open interval $I\supseteq [a,b]$ and a differentiable function $g:I\to\Bbb R$ such that $f=\left.g\right\rvert_{[a,b]}$.

(1) implies (2) by considering $I=\Bbb R$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if }a\le x\le b\ f(a)+(x-a)\lim_{t\to a^+}\frac{f(t)-f(a)}{t-a}&\text{if }x<a\ f(b)+(x-b)\lim_{t\to b^-}\frac{f(t)-f(b)}{t-b}&\text{if }x>b\end{cases}$.

What you should know is that some authors say a function $f$ defined on a closed interval $[p,q]$ (and only on that interval) is not differentiable at the endpoints of the interval. That says nothing about differentiability at any point inside the domain, or in particular any closed subinterval of the domain.
Case in point: let $f:[0,3]\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = x^2$.
Then $f$ is differentiable at every point in $[1,2],$ including the endpoints.
In both of your examples there is nothing to say that the interval $[a,b]$ is the only place where the function is defined. The function may be differentiable on all of $[a,b]$ if $f$ is defined on an interval that starts before $a$ and ends after $b$.
(By the way, some authors define limits in such a way that functions can be differentiable at endpoints of their domains without needing to specify that these are "one-sided" derivatives. But we don't need to be concerned with that here.)

By saying f is differentiable on [a,b] which is a closed interval it means by hypothesis that it is differentiable on every point on that interval, it's just a matter of how they wrote the theorem.
This also just seems to be an equivalent theorem to
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem
You can also find more (in italian but you can use a translator) in these 4 classic theorems
https://www.youmath.it/lezioni/analisi-matematica/derivate/232-i-principali-teoremi-sulle-derivate-fermat-rolle-cauchy-lagrange.html
